# Longest common substring bug

Tags: algorithm, lua, longest-substring

I have made this so far

```
function lcs(xstr, ystr)
        if xstr:len() == 0 or ystr:len() == 0 then
                return ""
        end
        x = xstr:sub(1,1)
        y = ystr:sub(1,1)
        xs = xstr:sub(2)
        ys = ystr:sub(2)
        if x == y then
                return x .. lcs(xs, ys)
        else
                l1 = lcs(xstr, ys)
                l2 = lcs(xs, ystr)
                if l1:len() > l2:len() then
                        return l1
                else
                        return l2
                end
        end
end

print(lcs("abcd", "bcd"))
```

unfortunately it prints just "d" and not "bcd" as expected. For me it looks like the line "l2 = lcs(xs, ystr)" hasn't be executed because if I add debug print at the beginning it prints that function hasn't been called wit arguments "bcd" and "bcd", but I'm sure that values are alright after beginning of else statement.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you know that your function has an exponential time complexity?

Comment: Yes, I do. Anyway thanks for telling me.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Yes. I know algorithm with running time O(mn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `xs` variable is global

```
l1 = lcs(xstr, ys)
l2 = lcs(xs, ystr)
```

First line corrupts `xs` value used by second line.
Make all your temporary variables (x, y, xs, ys, l1, l2) local.